# Compact Metric Space with sequence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

$(1)$ If $S$ is a compact metric space, and $\{x_{n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset S$ is a sequence with finitely many accumulation points, $y_{1}, \dots ,y_{k}$, then we can partition $\mathbb{N} = \cup_{j=1}^{k} S_{j} $, such that $ \{ x_{n} : n \in S_{j} \}$ converges to $y_{j}$, $\forall j \in [k]$. 
$(2)$ If $S$ is an arbitrary metric space and $\{x_{n} \}$ has a countably infinite amount of accumulation points, $y_{1}, y_{2} ,\dots $, then we can partition $\mathbb{N} = \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} S_{j}$ such that $\{ x_{n} : n \in S_{j} \}$ converges to $y_{j}$, $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$. 
 
For the first question, since $S$ is sequentially compact, we have that $\exists \{x_{n_{k}} \} \subset \{x_{n} \}$ such that $x_{n_{k}} \rightarrow y_{1}$. Then $S_{1} = \{n_{k} : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Then repeat the procedure on the sequence $X_{2} = \{ x_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus S_{1} \}$. It has a subsequence which converges by sequential compactness to $y_{2}$, and denote this index set as $S_{2}$. Then define $X_{t} = \{x_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{t} S_{j} \}$, and it has a subsequence which converges to $y_{t}$. Does this procedure work and if so why? 
For the arbitrary metric space, I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

No, your procedure does not work, because there is no guarantee that you will pick up every natural number, and hence you won't get a partition.

Instead, here's a way to proceed for (1). Let $r > 0$ be the minimal distance between pairs of points $y_1,...,y_k$. Let $\epsilon = r/3$. Consider the disjoint union of balls $U = B(y_1,\epsilon) \cup \cdots \cup B(y_k,\epsilon)$. Argue that there exists a natural number $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $x_n \in U$; if not then, applying sequential compactness, you'll get a subsequence that does not converge to any of $y_1,...,y_k$. You can now partition the infinite ray $\{N,N+1,N+2,N+3,...\}$ into $k$ sets, according to which of those balls contains $x_n$ for each $n \ge N$. The rest of the indices $\{1,...,N-1\}$ can be assigned to partition elements arbitrarily.

Comment: How does one generalize for any arbitrary metric space?

Comment: My answer is already stated for an arbitrary compact metric space.

Comment: Right, but if the compactness condition is not assumed then we can't repeat the argument since it relies on sequential compactness to obtain a partition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is your last comment asking about (2)? It was not clear from your post whether (2) was something you wanted answered, since the ensuing discussion in your post is all about (1).

Comment: Yes, for $(2)$, how can we extract a subsequence of $\{x_{n} \}$ which converges to one of the limit points, and then how do we obtain the relevant partition?

Comment: You can always extract a subsequence which converges to one of the limit points: the existence of such a subsequence is the actual *definition* of a limit point. I don't know how to do a partition to answer (2), and I'm not convinced such a partition must always exist.

Comment: I was thinking like $T_{1}, T_{2}, \dots $, are the index sets which converge to each $y_{1}, y_{2} , \dots $, and $T_{0} = \mathbb{N} \setminus \cup T_{i}$ and $T_{i} \cap T_{j}$ can be redistributed without affecting convergence of the subseqences